# How define a multivariate function in R

Tags: r, function

I have the following function:

[image]

I would like to write a function in `R` for `f`. It should take as arguments `x`, `c1`, ..., `cn` and `n`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the argument lengths are variable, use 3 dots (`...`)

```
f1 <- function(x, ...) {
              2 * x + sum((x - c(...))^2)
}
```

-testing

```
f1(5, 10, 5, 2, 3)
[1] 48
```

Comment: If your c values are in a vector, akrun's solution also works when called like this: `f1(5, c(10,5,2,3) )`